# Django: getting NoReverseMatch at / error

Tags: python, django

There are a lot of similar issues on SO and i went through most of them, but still unable to resolve my problem.

I am getting the following error:

> Reverse for 'category_view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{'pk': 'dynamic-programming'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
>   NoReverseMatch at /articles/

Here is my settings from urls.py file:

```
url(r'^category/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/$', views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category_view')
```

And, this is my definition of get_absolute_url() from model;

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
return reverse('category_view', kwargs={'pk': self.slug})
```

And the caller where I am getting this error is from index.html:

```
<li><a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
```

I am sure that I am missing something very obvious, but not able to figure it out for past few hours. :(

Content from project's urls.py:

```
url(r'^articles/$', include('blog.urls', namespace="blog")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Comment: Have you included urls.py in projects urls.py ?

Comment: yes, it is included in project's urls.py. updated my answer with the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you forgot to include the `urls.py` from your app into the project's `urls.py`.

**UPDATE**: if you used the `namespace` parameter of the include then you have to specify this namespace in the `reverse()` call:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:category_view', kwargs={'pk': self.slug})
```

Comment: Updated my question with the contents from project's urls.py.

Comment: Add the namespace to the `reverse()` call. See the update in my answer.

Comment: Now, I am getting this : Reverse for 'category_view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 'dynamic-programming'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['articles/$category/(?P<pk>[\\w-]+)/$']

Comment: Remove the dollar sign from the include regex: `url(r'^articles/', include('blog.urls', namespace="blog")),`

Comment: What version of django are you running on? Whilst @catavaran's answer is spot on, it's designed for 1.8+ anything lower than 1.8 requires the current_app attribute to be added to the reverse. `return reverse('blog:category_view', kwargs={'pk': self.slug}, current_app=self.request.resolver_match.namespace)`

Comment: @Neil, my django version is 1.9

Comment: @pankaj ok then you don't need to define the current_app on anything 1.8 or higher. That's just for clarification if anyone comes here looking for an answer for anything less than 1.8